# Java SwingWorker not updating reference to object from GUI

Tags: reference, swingworker

So I load some data from Database and use SwingWorker for it.

```
public class LoadFromDatabase extends SwingWorker<ArrayList<Ucet>, GuiUpdate>{

    private ArrayList<Ucet> ucty;
    private JLabel lblStav;
    private File dbPath;
    private JProgressBar progress;
    private int pocetUctov;
    private JButton btnLoad;
    private JButton btnStart;

    public LoadFromDatabase(ArrayList<Ucet> ucty,JLabel lblStav,File dbpath,JProgressBar progress, JButton btnLoad,JButton btnStart){
        this.ucty=ucty;
        this.lblStav=lblStav;
        this.dbPath=dbpath;
        this.progress=progress;
        this.btnLoad=btnLoad;
        this.btnStart=btnStart;

    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<Ucet> doInBackground() throws Exception {
        String sqlLoadUcty="SELECT email,password FROM members";
        ArrayList<Ucet> ucty2=new ArrayList<>();
        try {
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
          Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:"+dbPath.getPath());
          Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
          stmt.setQueryTimeout(30);
          ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sqlLoadUcty);
          GuiUpdate gd=new GuiUpdate(GuiUpdate.GuiType.setStartLoading);
          gd.setValue(0);
          publish(gd);
          pocetUctov=rs.getFetchSize();
          gd=new GuiUpdate(GuiUpdate.GuiType.setMaxValue); 
          gd.setValue(pocetUctov);
          publish(gd);
          int counter=0;
          while (rs.next()){
              Ucet uct=new Ucet(
                      rs.getString("email"),
                       rs.getString("password")
                      );
              gd=new GuiUpdate(GuiUpdate.GuiType.setValue);
              gd.setValue(counter);
              publish(gd);
              ucty2.add(uct);
          }

          rs.close();
          stmt.close();
          conn.close();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problem= "+ex);

        } catch (SQLException ex) {
             System.out.println("Problem= "+ex);

        }


        return ucty2;
    }


    @Override
    public void process(List<GuiUpdate> update){
        for (GuiUpdate guiUpdate : update) {
            if (guiUpdate.getToDo()==GuiUpdate.GuiType.setStartLoading) {
                lblStav.setText("Loading ...");
                progress.setVisible(true);
            } else if (guiUpdate.getToDo()==GuiUpdate.GuiType.setMaxValue) {
                progress.setMaximum(guiUpdate.getValue());
                pocetUctov=guiUpdate.getValue();
                progress.setMinimum(0);
            } else if (guiUpdate.getToDo()==GuiUpdate.GuiType.setValue) {
                progress.setValue(guiUpdate.getValue());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void done(){
        progress.setVisible(false);

        btnLoad.setEnabled(true);
        try {
            ucty=get();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problem= "+ex);
        } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
           System.out.println("Problem= "+ex);
        }
        if (ucty!=null && ucty.size()>0) {
            btnStart.setEnabled(true);
            lblStav.setText("Loaded "+ucty.size()+" accounts.");
        }
    }


}
```

This is whole SwingWorker. I basicly load data from DB and update progress bar.
Once loaded then done() method is called where reference to created ArrayList in doInbackground is set to arraylist which comes from mainGUI and some buttons are allowed and disallowed.

This is how I call SwingWorker from Gui:

```
private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        JFileChooser fileDb=new JFileChooser();
        int returnVal=fileDb.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (returnVal==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            databasePath=fileDb.getSelectedFile();
            jButton4.setEnabled(false);
            execurtor.execute(new LoadFromDatabase(naciatneUcty, jLabel9, databasePath, jProgressBar1, jButton4,jButton1));
        }
    }
```

This works great ,even if debug last line of code in SwingWorker done() I can clearly see that ArrayList ucty contians data from databse.

**Once back to main gui , ArrayList naciatneUcty is still null. 
But it should not be since I am sending it to SwingWorker where its reference should be updated...**

Where is the problem ,why reference is not updated at all?

Answer (score 0):

Java references are passed by value, so when you execute `ucty = get()` the reference inside the swingworker is changed, but that isn't going to update the reference for naciatneUcty.  You'd be better off instantiating naciatneUcty before running the swingworker, have doInBackground() return void, scrap utcy2 and then just grab utcy in the done() method.

Comment: "Once bact to main gui...", is also problematic.  You shouldn't think linearly with this.  done() is back to main gui.